# What is the difference if you write the security rules in these 2 ways?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The first method shown below is from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data). The second method just takes the `landmarks` match statement out of the `cities` one. Is there a difference? I'm using rules version 2, but was looking for an answer for both rules versions.

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;

        match /landmarks/{landmark} {
          allow read, write: if <condition>;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

vs

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /cities/{city} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
    match /cities/{city}/landmarks/{landmark} {
      allow read, write: if <condition>;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've shared them, there is no functional difference between the two rule sets as far as I can tell at first glance.

I typically prefer the first syntax, as it allows you to define functions in the `city` scope that are then available in nested rules too.